# When a specific form option is selected a new input appears, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, visibility

I'm trying to get the following concept working (bare in mind my JavaScript knowledge is minimal).

A select option is provided, with fields like:

- email
- address
- marriage

So on...

When a field is selected a input for that field needs to appear, I've worked out the way to get a single input to appear but when wanting more than one option to have its own input is where it gets confusing!

```
<select name="retrieveMarriage" onchange="document.getElementById('otherdetail').style.display = (this.selectedIndex === 2) ? 'block' : 'none';">
 <option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Select Field To Update</option>
<option value="No">Address</option>
<option value="Yes">Email</option>
</select>
<div id="otherdetail" style="display: none;">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter NEW Email..."       onClick="$(this).removeClass('placeholderclass')" class="dateclass placeholderclass">
</input></div><br>
```

Where am I going wrong? How would I make it so each option value has its own extra input that is made visible when being selected.

Comment: This appears to be a dup of your question three days prior. If something isn't working, it's best to continue with the same question, rather than have someone answer it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this is the answer that you were seeking but I'll give it a shot.

Instead of programming JavaScript inline you should either use it inside a `<script></script>` tag or in a JavaScript file. So what i did was that i set an Event Listener on the select field and what that does is that it listens to when you click, for instance:

```
var select = document.getElementById('retrieveMarriage');

// Where it says EVENT you can insert any event that you would like
select.addEventListener('EVENT', function() {});
```

And then you just insert some simple logic into the curly brackets. E.g. naming the hidden divs to something like "box-" followed by one of the numbers that you get from `this.selectedIndex`.

```
var select = document.getElementById('retrieveMarriage');
var currentOption = 0;

// Add event listener that listens on when you click "select"
select.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // If one of the other options are selected, then hide it and set it to empty
    if(currentOption > 0) {
        document.getElementById('box-' + currentOption).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('box-' + currentOption).firstChild.value = '';
    }
    // Set current option to be current option
    currentOption = this.selectedIndex;
    // Set box-N to show
    document.getElementById('box-' + currentOption).style.display = 'block';
});
```

You can check my solution out in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6ypytx2p/

Here is a full list of events that you can use.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

I hope I was able to answer your question.

Comment: this is great! Only thing is, when selecting email the address input appears, not quite sure what to alter

Comment: @ili Have you set them in the correct order (both the select options and hidden <div> tags)? Remember that when selecting the first option, the #box-1 div will show. If you're still experiencing the problem then upload it to jsbin/jsfiddle and ill take a look.